# No data passed to a "Create" view object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My MVC app has a strange behavior that I do not understand.

When I click on the "Create" actionLink, the view generated is as designed. So I fill the fields with proper values to test the behavior.

But when I click on the "Create" button, the object passed to the controlled has all the fields to null and an id of 0, and I really don't get why it does so.

Here is the controller method that deals with Create:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ObjInfo _obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        m_ObjManager.CreateObj(_obj);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(_obj);
}
```

And here's how I have coded my "Create" View:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ObjInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create New Object</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>OBJ</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Address)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_City)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_ContactName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_ContactName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_ContactName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_ContactTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_ContactTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_ContactTitle)
        </div>

        (...)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Link", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I am ready to offer my code to solve this issue, if needed.

```
namespace MyApp.Models 
{
    public class ObjInfo 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties declaration.
        /// </summary>
        public int m_ID;
        public string m_Address;
        public string m_City;
        public string m_ContactName;
        public string m_ContactTitle;
        public string m_Country;
        public string m_Name;
        public string m_Email;
        public string m_FaxNumber;
        public string m_Notes;
        public string m_PhoneNumber;
        public string m_PostalCode;
        public string m_Region;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public CustomerInfo()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overloaded constructor with parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_adress"></param>
        /// <param name="_city"></param>
        /// <param name="_contactName"></param>
        /// <param name="_contactTitle"></param>
        /// <param name="_country"></param>
        /// <param name="_customerID"></param>
        /// <param name="_name"></param>
        /// <param name="_mail"></param>
        /// <param name="_faxNumber"></param>
        /// <param name="_notes"></param>
        /// <param name="_phoneNumber"></param>
        /// <param name="_postalCode"></param>
        /// <param name="_region"></param>
        public CustomerInfo(string _adress, string _city, string _contactName, string _contactTitle, string _country, int _customerID, string _customerName,
            string _mail, string _faxNumber, string _notes, string _phoneNumber, string _postalCode, string _region)
        {
            this.m_Address = _adress;
            this.m_City = _city;
            this.m_ContactName = _contactName;
            this.m_ContactTitle = _contactTitle;
            this.m_Country = _country;
            this.m_CustomerID = _customerID;
            this.m_CustomerName = _customerName;
            this.m_EbayCustomer = _ebayCustomer;
            this.m_Email = _mail;
            this.m_FaxNumber = _faxNumber;
            this.m_Notes = _notes;
            this.m_PhoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
            this.m_PostalCode = _postalCode;
            this.m_Region = _region;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Destructor.
        /// </summary>
        ~CustomerInfo()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose method.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To add more detail to my post: in debug mode, when I hover over the _obj in the controller, as mentioned before, all the parameters are set to null and the Id is 0.

Comment: Is there another method in your controller that renders the view? Are you passing the ObjInfo model to it?

Comment: please add your Model to your post

Comment: Well, it's builded as an MVC, so there's an index, edit, create, delete and details method, but right now I'm mostly concerned about the Create method shown up there.
There are 2 methods: one Create that works as a GET, while the other is an HTTPPost.

Comment: @DaveA Done! The model is now updated in the edit.

Comment: Does that model compiles?

Comment: @rae1n Yes, without any bugs, crashes, or exceptions.

Comment: You have a class called `ObjInfo` with a constructor called `CustomerInfo`, making that model non-compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your model class has public setters on each property, i.e.,

```
public string m_Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: I advice you to use properties instead of public fields. Your properties should look like this:

public string Address { get { return m_Address; } set { m_Address = value; } }

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace MyApp.Models 
{
    public class ObjInfo 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties declaration.
        /// </summary>
        public int m_ID {get; set;};
        public string m_Address {get; set;};
        public string m_City {get; set;};
        public string m_ContactName {get; set;};
        public string m_ContactTitle {get; set;};
        public string m_Country {get; set;};
        public string m_Name {get; set;};
        public string m_Email {get; set;};
        public string m_FaxNumber {get; set;};
        public string m_Notes {get; set;};
        public string m_PhoneNumber {get; set;};
        public string m_PostalCode {get; set;};
        public string m_Region {get; set;};
```

Comment: I do understand the point of having getter setters, but every model I have is built like I posted up there without any impact whatsoever. So please believe me when I say this is not the answer to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, tho. I will probably update my code eventually to adopt this behavior, but right now I'm focusing on making things work instead.

Comment: @HervéSimard, humor me and try. I could be wrong, but I'm convinced this is the issue. I thought so when I asked to see your model.

Comment: Ok, I admit, you were right! I thought that it was okay, but after rewieving you were right: other classes DO have getters and setters, and I forgot to put some with this one.